# "I have prepared on mysql call procedure/function. But while call the procedure/function error is coming."

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE mmyyyy DATE;
    DECLARE retval INT(1);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT B.TMA_MONTH 
        FROM TRN_EMPLOYEE_MASTER A 
        LEFT JOIN TRN_MONTHLY_ATTENDANCE B 
            ON A.TEM_STAFFNO = B.TMA_STAFFNO 
        WHERE B.TMA_MONTH = mnth 
          AND A.ACT_FLAG = 'Y';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;    
    SET retval = 1;
    SET mmyyyy = mnth;

    OPEN cur1;  

        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO mmyyyy;         
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            IF mmyyyy IS NULL THEN
                SET retval = 0;
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;

    RETURN retval;
END
```

`mmyyyy` is the date when payroll will run like: `'2020-01-01'`

`mnth` is date of run of payroll i.e. `'2020-01-01'`

PHP code to call the function given below

error after rum the php script:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR), expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\finance\payrollprocess.php on line 19

```
<?php
$servername = "10.100.1.45";
$username = "csnis";
$password = "csnis";
$dbname = "hpvp1";
$port = "3306";

DECLARE mmyyyy DATE;
DECLARE retval INT(1);
SET mmyyyy = mnth;
SELECT mnth ;
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($con,'hpvp1');

$result=mysqli_query($con,CALL tpayroll_attendance_check(mnth))or die(mysqli_error($con));
While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "successful";  
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Include procedure header/definition into SQL code. Specify what line is "line 19" mentioned in error message.

Comment: I see SQL statements in PHP code (DECLARE, SET, SELECT) - this is wrong.

Comment: I am very new to PHP. Please help me providing with correct code.

Comment: /*  
Description:tpayroll_attendance_check. Run the attendance table. in the attendance table staffno, month (for january 2020-01-01, for february 2020-02-01 as on) and active_flag=Y ( those who are present on this month)  
Author:   
Create Date: jan 2020
Param:mnth value=(2020-02-01)   
Return: 1  
Modified Date:2020-01-01  
Modification: month column changed to 2020-02-01 for 2nd month 
*/